# Can Grafana Dashboard Gauge Visualisation method show a value from time series based on the time range?

Tags: json, grafana

I am using Grafana Cloud Dashboard, having the following JSON data, loaded by the JSON API:

```
[
  {"time": "2024-02-14 9:01:00", "val": 10}, 
  {"time": "2024-02-14 9:02:00", "val": 32}, 
  ...
  {"time": "2024-02-15 11:59:00", "val": 488}
]
```

The data is recorded every minute. Given that the Dashboard selected time range is within the time range specified in the JSON API (e.g. 2024-02-14 to 2024-02-16), I want to display the `val` in a Gauge visualisation panel in Grafana Dashboard, and the gauge displays a value every second. Is it possible to do so?